# java Temporarily adding CA seems to malfunction

Tags: java, keystore, ca

Since not all jvm's have letsencrypt yet in their cacert keystore, I need to temporarily add it when running a program. My code is as follows:

```java
public void addRootCA() throws Exception {
    InputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("letsencrypt.crt"));
    Certificate ca = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(fis);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, null);
    ks.setCertificateEntry("LetsEncrypt CA", ca);
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
}
```

It does seem to add the certificate (the exceptions for it being missing disappears and I get a response on the serverside) but it seems that the other CA's from the default java key store aren't loaded anymore. I got the code mostly from another stackoverflow question that was marked as the right answer, so I am puzzled that it doesn't behave appropriately.

What is the reason that other CA's don't get loaded? Or is there maybe an entirely different problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Java keystore isn't loading because you aren't loading it. You're loading it from `null` which creates an empty keystore. You would need to locate the default Java keystore, open it, load from it, and close it.

Comment: I thought that I read somewhere that null defaults to the default java keystore, but I might have been wrong. What is the easiest way to access this keystore? Does Java provide something to make locating it easier?

Comment: I found a way to access the current truststore in another thread. Thanks for your help

Comment: For reference, this is a way to access the keystore:

`Path ksPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "lib", "security", "cacerts");
keyStore.load(Files.newInputStream(ksPath),
                    "changeit".toCharArray());`